# Proof by contradiction that $P \rightarrow Q$ is true

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

Let $\tau$ be a closed tableau. Prove that $\tau$ is not satisfiable.

So let's say the statement can be expressed by $P \rightarrow Q$. To prove that this statement is true, we look at the assumption that $\neg (P \rightarrow Q)$. We know that $P \rightarrow Q$ being false means that  $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.

So I have to prove $C \wedge \neg C$

[image]

Then I know that:

A tableau is complete iff every rule that can be applied has been appled.

A branch is closed iff there are formulas of the form $A$ and $\neg A$ on two of its nodes.

A branch is open iff it is not closed.

A tableau is closed iff every branch is closed, otherwise it is open.

So the statement, $\tau$ is a closed tableau then $\tau$ is not satisfiable, is true.

Am I correct?

Comment: Your argument looks like a [non sequitur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(logic)) ... Following you approach, in order to prove $p \to q$ you have to show that from $p$ and $\lnot q$ a *contradiction* follows (and thus conclude by *Indirect Proof*). Thus, you have to show the contradiction implied by $p$ : "$\tau$ is closed" and $\lnot q$ : "$\tau$ is satisfiable".

Comment: Can you elaborate

Answer (score 1):

$P\to Q$ does not generate a closed tableau. Using this [tree proof generator](https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/) one can find a countermodel:

[image]

The domain is irrelevant in this tool's output for propositional logic, but if $P$ is true and $Q$ is false then the antecedent is true and the consequent is false, hence the conditional is invalid.

In the tree presented in the diagram, both $P\to Q$ and $\neg(P\to Q)$ were added to the tree. Since these are contradictory, they would lead to a closed tree.

If the tableau $\tau$ is satisfiable then there exists a branch of the tree that is not closed upon which one can construct a countermodel to the validity of the original statement. Since by assumption $\tau$ is closed, no such branch exists and so the tableau is not satisfiable.

---

Tree Proof Generator. https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/